# What does mono.onErrorResume(Mono:error) do?

Tags: project-reactor

I'm working a new project and the codebase is filled with statements like this one:

```
someFunctionThatReturnsAMono().onErrorResume(Mono::error)...
```

Where the function's prototype could be:

```
public Mono<Data> someFunctionThatReturnsAMono()
```

What does this `onErrorResume(Mono::error)` do ? No one could explain, and my understanding is that `onErrorResume` is only called when we already have a `Mono::error`, so the statement would be in fact useless.

[Link to the projectreactor's onErrorResume doc.](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#onErrorResume-java.util.function.Function-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It adds nothing (except another step on the schedular), it just unwraps and rewraps the throwable from/to a Error signal.
Note that it does nothing to the throwable itself, so it wont have a "cause" or anything like that.

```
@Test
public void rethrow() {
    StepVerifier.create(Mono.just("hi")
                            .handle((it, sink) -> sink.error(new RuntimeException(it)))
                            .log("sink")
                            .onErrorResume(it -> Mono.error(it))
                            .log("resume"))
                .expectSubscription()
                .expectError(RuntimeException.class)
                .verify();
}
```

equivalent imperitive code would look something like:

```
    try{
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }catch (RuntimeException ex){
        throw ex;
    }
```

you could read more on this at: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#which.errors

Comment: Thank you for your answer that's what I thought but I'd rather be cautious when altering production code. Am I right to understand that I can safely remove all occurences of `onErrorResume(Mono::error)` ?

Comment: Actually, does it change something if it is applied to a Flux instead of a Mono ? As in: `flux.onErrorResume(Mono::error)`

Comment: unless there is something really freaky going on (race conditions due to scheduling stuff that accudentally means things work) you can safely remove it.
If you want to be certain, just write a regression test for it.
also, the same applies for flux.

Comment: yes, I can confirm this kind of statement is useless and can be removed, and the Flux-and-MonoError combination doesn't have any particular effect either